# In underscore.js/lodash.js, how to remove duplicate tuple using `uniq`?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

Here is the expression

```
_([1,2],[1,3],[1,2]).uniq().value()
```

The evaluated value is

```
[[1,2],[1,3],[1,2]]
```

Though what I expect is `[[1,2],[1,3]]`..

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Underscore uses strict equality on the list if you don't supply a predicate. So in your example underscore will be checking that a value is in the result array by comparing 2 arrays e.g. `[1,2] === [1,2]` which will always be false as they are two different arrays.

One quick 'n' dirty solution would be:

```
var result = _.uniq(data, function (a) {
    return a.join(',');
});
```

Comment: Any reason for the downvote on the 29 of Sep 2015? If there's a problem with the answer then please add a comment and I'll correct it. Nobody learns from anonymous downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare uniqueness using [isEqual()](https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual), which is a fairly versatile approach, I would do something like this:

```
_.reduce(coll, function(result, item) {
    if (!_.any(result, _.ary(_.partial(_.isEqual, item), 1))) {
        result.push(item);
    }
    return result;
}, []);
```

Using [reduce()](https://lodash.com/docs#reduce), you start off with an empty array. Then [any()](https://lodash.com/docs#some) tells you if the current item is already in the `results` array. If not, it adds it.

Using `toString()` to compare compare complex values can lead to inconsistencies. However, most of the time it's sufficient - use this approach if you end up with unexpected results.

Comment: The `_.ary(..., 1)` is completely unnecessary. `_.partial(_.isEqual, item)` already returns a function that takes one argument. Good answer tho otherwise.